# Give reviewers/editor a bit of lead time before the newsletter is sent to users

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

This is more of a StackExchange network request than one for SO itself, but here goes:

Generally speaking the bit of logic that picks questions for the email newsletter does a good job of picking questions that are interesting to people who subscribe to the newsletter.

Since these questions are sent to all the subscribers, I like to make sure that they're of high quality and give people an impression that they're getting the best of the best. When I receive the newsletter I typically open each one, do some edits, clean things up, flag, and other typical things I normally do in the /review queue.

I think it would be great if there was a bit of a lead time for people who unlocked the /review privileges to either get the newsletter a little bit earlier or perhaps have those questions pop up in the /review queue so that they can have some human eyeballs give them a once over and improve them if need be.

Comment: Cool idea, if it's practical.

Comment: could've sworn there was a dupe regarding this, can't find now :\

Answer (score 4):

This already exists, sort of:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/

What you might want is a way to filter that by time so you can curate the recent "greatest hits" that are likely to go out in the newsletter.

Basically what I am trying to say here is, you should be gardening your prize roses all the time, not just before the big flower show. :)

Comment: Agreed on the latter - its just that every once in awhile, one really low quality question slips through the cracks. Rather embarrassing.

Comment: Yeah a "New" tab there or whatever would be enough I think.